# Spring file upload with two file upload elements

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a form with two file upload elements and those are supporting for multiple files upload. 
My question is how can I get the data of both file upload elements.

Eg: I need fields of both **"files"** and **"files2"** elements.

With the following code I am only able to get the details of one file upload element. 
I am new to Spring  and hope my question is clear.

[image]

```
<table id="fileTable">  
<tr>
    <td><label for="file">Image URL</label></td>
    <td><input type="file" name="files[0]" id="file"></input></td>  
    <td><input id="addFile" type="button" value="Add Image URL" /></td> 
</tr>

<tr id="img_hover">
    <td><label for="file2">Image Hover URL</label></td>
    <td><input type="file" name="files2[0]" id="file2"></input></td>    
    <td><input id="addFile2" type="button" value="Add Image Hover URL" /></td>  
</tr>   

<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save.action", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView save(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,           
        @ModelAttribute("uploadForm") FileUploadForm uploadForm

        ) {

    List<MultipartFile> files = uploadForm.getFiles();
    List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (null != files && files.size() > 0) {

        for (MultipartFile multipartFile : files) {

            String fileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
            fileNames.add(fileName);
            System.out.println(fileName);

        }
    }

    return new ModelAndView("index", "model", "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be other blocking issues, but the one that stands out is your file input fields are not properly named to be picked up as a collection.

```
<input type="file" name="files[0]" id="file"
...
<input type="file" name="files2[0]" id="file"
```

should be

```
<input type="file" name="files[0]" id="file"
...
<input type="file" name="files[1]" id="file"
```

In the first version, they will be treated as 2 different file collections, one named `files` and another named `files2`.

**Update to OP comment:**

The problem is you've defined 2 file fields in your form that belong to different collections (e.g. files, files2), but you're only getting one of the collections - `files` (e.g. uploadForm.getFiles()). If your intention is to keep the files in separate collections, then you'll need to add another collection to FileUploadForm

```
private List<MultiparfFile> files;
private List<MultipartFile> files2;
```

and then in your controller

```
uploadForm.getFiles();   //for file fields named files
uploadForm.getFiles2();  //for file fields named files2
```

Comment: In my form there are two file upload elements. one is file[] and other one is file2[]. So when the form is submitted I should be able to get the values form both file[] and file2[]